# How to create a table in a specific page in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

I am using XSL-FO.

I want to start a table in the 2nd page of the output PDF file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What FO processor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [**break property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#keepbreak) to force a page break in a specific position:

- either add [`break-after="page"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#break-after) the the last FO element preceding the table
- or add [`break-before="page"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#break-before) to the `fo:table` element itself.

Note that the resulting effect is to have the table at the beginning of *a* page: whether it is actually at the beginning of the *second* page depends on the amount of content preceding the table. The table could end up at the beginning of page *3* if there is a lot of text before it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your formatter's behavior of float "after". RenderX XEP would float whatever is inside (in your case a table) to the following page top from where it occurs. So you could create a float marker "after" right at the start of your flow and it would occur at the start of the second page.

This would assume that (1) you want the table on the top of the page and (2) the table itself is not longer than a page. A float cannot break across a page in this case.